# Expanding and sympifying an expression when using typesetting format

Tags: simplifying-expressions, formatting

I'm starting to learn Mathematica, and in the book that I'm reading the author presented the commands `Simplify` and `Expand`. Now, the example in the book was the following:

```
Simplify[(x^3 - y^3)/(x - y)]
```

In the above form , evaluation works and outputs

> ```
> x^2 + x y + y^2
> ```

The problem is, when I use the typesetting notation, the function doesn't work:

Simplify[$\frac{x^3 - y^3}{x-y}$]

The above command outputs $\frac{x^3 - y^3}{x-y}$, instead of the simplified  form. The same happens for the command "Expand".

Is there a way around this? As asked in the comment, here is the output of

Simplify[$\frac{x^3 - y^3}{x-y}$]\FullForm

```
\!\(
TagBox[
StyleBox[
RowBox[{"Times", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Power", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Plus", "[", 
RowBox[{"x", ",", 
RowBox[{"Times", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1"}], ",", "y"}], "]"}]}], "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"-", "1"}]}], "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"Plus", "[", 
RowBox[{"x\\.b3", ",", 
RowBox[{"Times", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1"}], ",", "y\\.b3"}], "]"}]}], "]"}]}], "]"}],
ShowSpecialCharacters->False,
ShowStringCharacters->True,
NumberMarks->True],
FullForm]\)
```

Comment: Can you add //FullForm (i.e., Simplify[..] //FullForm)? This should make clear what is going wrong.

Comment: Will try. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the question with the output of the FullForm, but I'm new to Mathematica, I have not been able to identify the issue.

Comment: How would you enter `x^3` using "typesetting notation"? It seems that your `x^3` is actually `x` followed by the unicode character $\unicode{179}$. That is not how you typeset `x^3` in Mathematica. Instead use Ctrl-^ to create a superscript.

Comment: I think it might be a configuration in my Ubuntu then. You are right, by using crtl-^ it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must have made a mistake when entering the expression in typeset form. When I pasted the LaTeX form

$\frac{x^3 - y^3}{x-y}$

After entering

```
Simplify[
```

and pasting the LaTeX form, I got a dialog pane asking me if wanted the front-end to translate from LaTeX to Mathematica typesetting. I said yes, and then adding the closing bracket and evaluating got the following result

[image: simplify]

In box form the `Simplify` expression looks like this:

[image: boxes]

which not at all what you have. I also entered the typeset expression directly into my notebook with the Basic Math Assistant palette and got the same result.